# JAXB require boolean

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I am trying to generate a XSD file with a boolean element that is always required.
When I use the XSD file to generate the java classes (with JAXB) the field is not required.

I have attempted the following versions:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:tns="http://com.my.example/test"
           targetNamespace="http://com.my.example/test"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:complexType name="MyComplexElement">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MySimpleElement" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false"/>
            <xs:element name="MySimpleElement2" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

That XSD file generates me the following fields in the Java class:

```java
    @XmlElement(name = "MySimpleElement")
    protected boolean mySimpleElement;
    @XmlElement(name = "MySimpleElement2", required = true, type = Boolean.class, nillable = true)
    protected Boolean mySimpleElement2;
```

Whereas I was expecting something like this:

```java
    @XmlElement(name = "MySimpleElement", required=true) // This one would be my preferred one
    protected boolean mySimpleElement;
    @XmlElement(name = "MySimpleElement2", required = true, type = Boolean.class, nillable = false)
    protected Boolean mySimpleElement2;
```

I also have attempted to generate the XSD file from a java class but I wasn't able to do it either.

Note: I am using org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2-maven-plugin version:2.5.0

Comment: I am not sure if I have understand you, Isn't `use=required`  only available for attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An xml element of type `xs:boolean` which is not nillable can be represented in java by primitive data type `boolean` because a `boolean` always has a value (`true` or `false`) - it cannot be `null`.  Because it always has a value, it is not needed to specifically mark it as required to have the xml element generated.

An xml element of type `xs:boolean` which is nillable cannot be represented by primitive data type `boolean` because a `boolean` cannot be null. Therefore it is represented by a `Boolean` **object**. Because it can be null, it is needed to specifically mark it as required to have the xml element generated even if it is `null`.